# Adding Cloudflare SSL Results in 522 Error

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

Currently I'm trying to install a Cloudflare SSL certificate on my Ubuntu server that uses Nginx. I am following this [guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-setup-cloudflare-origin-certificates-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/) on how to do so, but once I successfully install the certificate as per the instructions, my host seems to stop working and Cloudflare shows an Error 522 when visiting my domain.

My Nginx Configuration:

```
ubuntu:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ cat ascend.so
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name  ascend.so;
    root   /var/www/html/ascend.so;
    index  index.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare_ascend.so.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cloudflare_key_ascend.so.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/origin-pull-ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
  
    autoindex off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

`$ cat /var/log/nginx` shows this:

```
2022/05/20 13:30:48 [error] 9267#9267: *112 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /db/db-admin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:49 [error] 9267#9267: *113 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:49 [error] 9267#9267: *114 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phpmyadmin2017/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:49 [error] 9267#9267: *115 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.1.1/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:49 [error] 9267#9267: *116 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin-5.1.0/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:50 [error] 9267#9267: *117 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phppma/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
2022/05/20 13:30:50 [error] 9267#9267: *118 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 45.9.135.234, server: ascend.so, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin-4.9.7/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1", host: "3.15.150.145"
```

Which is very weird since I'm not even using PHP.

Comment: it's a uncommon log format. please use the native way due its missing the http status

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.